# What's the difference between "the third day running" and "three days running"?

Tags: meaning

Their meanings seem the same. Are there any difference between them?

> India's Prime Minister Narendra Modi has Urged Hindus not together for a major religious festival as the country continues to register record numbers of coronavirus cases.【Infections are at an all-time high for the third day running with 234,000 new cases.】

Could " the third day running"  in this sentence be replaced by "three days running"?

Comment: @Cascabel ok, I'll add a text

Comment: Your example sentence would seem to be too long for a headline, but too ungrammatical for a sentence. i.e.  "...Modi has Urged Hindus not together for a major religious festival " appears to be missing the  second verb following the catenative verb "urge".

Comment: @Cascabel not to gather ???

Comment: If it said "three days running," it could be misconstrued that there were 234,000 new cases three days in a row so a total of 702,000 new cases. "Third day running" makes it clear that there are only 234,000 new cases, not 702,000 new cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Infections are at an all-time high for the third day running with 234,000 new cases."
> Could " the third day running" in this sentence be replaced by "three
> days running"?

Not really. The case total given refers only to the third day, not to each of the last three days. *Three days running* usually refers to three consecutive days in a continuous sense. *The third day running* focuses on the last of three consecutive days and evokes a day-by-day, as opposed to continuous, sense of time. Since the case counts are daily tallies, you want to be able to bin* the tallies day by day.

It's been raining for three days running. We had an inch of rain today for the third day running.

*breaking up a continuous stream of events into sets of hourly, daily or weekly totals is called binning.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused and have some questions. "【The third day running】 focuses on the last of three consecutive days and evokes a day-by-day, as opposed to continuous,sense of time." probably means every three days? Such as, He goes to school for three days running. (if Mon& Tue & Wed) He has history class for the third day running. (every Wednesday? Because of " evokes a day-by-day", he has history class even on the following Thursday and Friday?)